# Fullcalendar refresh after clicking to a particular events

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar

Currently, I am using a modal popup inside the fullCalendar event. The issue is on calendar Month view, Week view and day view, after clicking any event on the event that is at the  bottom part of the calendar , The modal opens but the calendar components refresh and take me to the top of the page.

Modal Component:

```html
export default function TimetablePopupData(timetableEvent) {   
  const timetableType     = {"Exam":"Exam","Teaching" :"Teaching" }   
    return timetableEvent?.event?.description?.timetableType === timetableType.Teaching ? (
      <dl>
        <dt>Activity:</dt> <dd>{timetableEvent?.event?.description?.activity}</dd>
        <dt>Type:</dt> <dd>{timetableEvent?.event?.description?.type}</dd>
        <dt>Room:</dt> <dd>{timetableEvent?.event?.description?.room}</dd>
      </dl>
    ) : (
      <dl>
        <dt>Start:</dt> <dd>{timetableEvent?.event?.description?.start}</dd>
        <dt>End:</dt> <dd>{timetableEvent?.event?.description?.end}</dd>
        <dt>Room:</dt> <dd>{timetableEvent?.event?.description?.room}</dd>
      </dl>
    );}
```

```html
  return(
<BoxWithHeading gridColumn={{ md: "9/25", lg: "7/25"}} gridRow="1 / 13" heading="Timetable" hasButton={false} >
  <Box>
  <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
    <ModalOverlay />
    <ModalContent background={bgColor} color={color}>
      <ModalHeader color={event?.description?.timetableType === timetableType.Teaching?teachingTitleColor: examTitleColor} fontSize="15px" fontWeight="600" pt="10" pb="1" pl="8">{CapitalizeEachWord(event?.title)}</ModalHeader>
      <ModalCloseButton />
      <ModalBody fontSize="13px" lineHeight="140%" px="8" py="0">           
      <TimetablePopupData event={event}/>
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter pt="0">
        <Button  fontSize="13px" py="1.5" px="4" height="auto" colorScheme='teal' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
          Close
        </Button>           
      </ModalFooter>
    </ModalContent>
  </Modal>

  <FullCalendar   initialView       = "timeGridFiveDaysWeek"
    height            = "auto"
    nowIndicator      = {true}
    headerToolbar     = {{left: "prev,next today",
                          center: "title",
                          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridFiveDaysWeek,timeGridDay"
                        }}
    plugins           = {[interaction, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin]}
    slotMinTime       = {"07:00:00"}
    slotMaxTime       = {"22:00:00"}
    locale            = {'en-gb'}
    firstDay          = {1}
    eventTimeFormat   = {{hour: '2-digit',minute: '2-digit',hour12: false}}
    views             = {{
                          timeGridFiveDaysWeek:{type: 'timeGridWeek',duration:{days: 7},buttonText: 'week',dateAlignment: 'week',slotEventOverlap:false},
                          dayGridMonth:{displayEventEnd:true, dayMaxEvents:6,moreLinkClick:"day"},
                          timeGridDay:{slotEventOverlap:false}
                        }}
    eventInteractive  = {true}
    eventClick        = {(eventData)=>{onOpen();setEvent(GetEventDetails(eventData))}}        
    eventSources      = {GetEventSources(data,isValid)}
    eventDidMount     = {handleEventMount}       
    eventDataTransform= {(eventData):any=>{TransformData(eventData)}}        
  />
</Box>
  </BoxWithHeading>
  ) 
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated.